# how to apply filter on inside array in array of dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, filter

I have a situation like i have array of dictionaries, in which each key has array of specific object. like this.

```
    // example setup
    struct FruitsData {
        var name: String?
        var id: String?
    }

tableViewSource = [String : [FruitsData]]
```

so i have to apply filter on this inner array. but i am unable to update the value in final array.
I have written this code.

```
tableViewSource = tableViewSource.filter { ( dictData: (key: String, value: [FruitsData])) -> Bool in
    var arrFruitsData = dictData.value
    arrFruitsData = arrFruitsData.filter{ ( $0.id != nil) }

    if arrFruitsData.count == 0 {
        self.tableViewHeaders = self.tableViewHeaders.filter { $0 != dictData.key }
    }
    return true

    }
```

like i have remove those values in array whose id has been removed.

for eg if i have these values in array.

```
var array = ["A": [FruitsData(name: "apple", id: "5"), FruitsData(name: "apricot",id: "")], "M": [FruitsData(name: "mango", id: "9"),    FruitsData(name: "grapes", id: "")]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `tableViewSource` is not the `Array` of Dictionary, it is `Dictionary` with each key having Array as value. Also from you example `id` is not `nil` but `empty` if you want remove object of `FruitsData` whose id is `nil` or `empty` you can make it like this.

```
var tableViewSource = [String : [FruitsData]]()
tableViewSource.forEach {
    let res = $1.filter { $0.id != nil && $0.id != "" }
    tableViewSource[$0] = res
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. it solved my problem. but is this not an array of dictionaries?

Comment: @user1960279 Welcome mate :) Yes it not array of dictionaries it is dictionary having all values as array